# Error with Propel and ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework, propel

After inheriting some Zend Framework code it didn't work, after lots of fiddling I've managed to create the schema and rebuild the models, although now I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Criteria::hasSelectClause() in  home/richard/library/om/BaseDomainPeer.php on line 329
```

Why would propel generate files that call unknown methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code was built on a system using the beta version of propel, when i forced my system to use the beta version, it worked.

to use the beta version, go [here](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/wiki/Users/Download)

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you have a name collision and you load some other class called Criteria and you don't realize it because of autoloading. Try dumping the methods using [get_class_methods()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php)